# How can get start and end time on fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

how can i get *start* and *end* time of visible days in fullcalendar?

I need it for use in another javascript instace. Is there some function like -

```
$('calender').getStartTime();
```

?

Answer (score 50):

If you're looking for the **visible** start and end date, that would be the `visStart` and `visEnd` property of the view object in **version 1**:

```
$('calender').fullCalendar('getView').visStart

$('calender').fullCalendar('getView').visEnd
```

and that would be `intervalStart` and `intervalEnd` in **version 2**:

```
$('calender').fullCalendar('getView').intervalStart

$('calender').fullCalendar('getView').intervalEnd
```

If you're looking for the start and end date of the current week / month, that would be the `start` and `end` property of the current view object:

```
$('calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start

$('calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end
```

Reference : [Full Calendar documentation.](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/)

Comment: In the latest version (V2), the properties are `intervalStart` and `intervalEnd` instead of `visStart` and `visEnd` (docs: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/) :-)

Comment: This answer is great, however the wording confused me slightly. `intervalStart` and `intervalEnd` are the beginning and end of the time interval the calendar _wants_ to represent, so for example they will be first and last day of current month, even if days from previous/next month are shown. `start` and `end` give the beginning and end of the actual time that is shown, including days outside of month.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why I'm seeing such different behavior but thanks to the others, I got in the right direction but the "start" and "end" are moment() objects. Thus to get the actual date, you need to use:

```
$('calendar').fullCalendar("getView").start.format()
$('calendar').fullCalendar("getView").end.format()
```

Works exactly like I need and what the OP asked. NOTE: The end date is one day after the calendar. That is, the calendar I'm looking at starts on Sunday 7/31/16 ends on Saturday 9/10/16 - and the date given me are 2016-07-31 and 2016-09-11 (one day after the date shown technically - of course if you say "00:00:00" of those days you'll be accurate).

Answer (score 6):

**version 5**

```
var start = calendar.view.activeStart;
var end = calendar.view.activeEnd;
```

Docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object

Answer (score 4):

**version 4**

You can just use calendar object and get satrt/end dates

```
 var start = calendar.view.view.activeStart;
 var end = calendar.view.view.activeEnd;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start
$('calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give id/class what you specified jquery full calendar

```
    var start_date =  $('#schedule-events').fullCalendar('getView').start
    var end_date  =   $('#schedule-events').fullCalendar('getView').end
```

Above #schedule-events of the full calendar .. you should give the id of the full calendar

Example :

```
   $('#schedule-events').fullCalendar({

            eventRender: function(event, element) {

          var start_date =  $('#schedule-events').fullCalendar('getView').start
          var end_date  =   $('#schedule-events').fullCalendar('getView').end
          console.log(start_date +'sart----------end date'+end_date)

                  }
```

......................etc..........

Answer (score 2):

Just posting it for others who might be looking for angular solution.

For start date `this.calendar.getApi().view.activeStart` and for end date
`this.calendar.getApi().view.activeEnd`

You can follow https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular to get fullcalendar api 
 - getApi() to use above methods.