# Angular Fullcalendar min and max time not working in month view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

Full calendar min and max time not working in month view.
But it is working in week and day view

```
minTime: "06:00:00",
maxTime: "30:00:00",
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `minTime`:

   - Determines the starting time that will be displayed, even when the scrollbars have been scrolled all the way up.

     > Duration, default: "00:00:00"
   - The default "00:00:00" means the start time will be at the very beginning of the day (midnight).
2. `maxTime`:

   - Determines the end time (exclusively) that will be displayed, even when the scrollbars have been scrolled all the way down.

     > Duration, default: "24:00:00"
   - The default "24:00:00" means the end time will be at the very end of the day (midnight).

Basically it follows clock times, you can't just say the max time is `30` hours.

Comment: Thank you for replay.
I just want to change calendar time slot 
6 am  to next day 5 am,   24 hours 
how can I change?

Comment: You will need to set a starting date and an end date.  Basically you will need a date + time. `angular date-time format`: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: What is the parameter of calendar config for setting a start date and an end date?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598768/how-do-i-determine-the-start-and-end-date-on-the-agendaweek-view-in-fullcalendar & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967910/how-can-get-start-and-end-time-on-fullcalendar will help you out with it. You can also look on google how to set a start and end date.

Comment: @user2194080 did the answer help? please review it or post your own answer if it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

> "//jsfiddle.net/rajesh13yadav/71g7n36t/1/embed/"

please include the above script link into your script tag to check the example.

You need to set min and max:
      **minTime:'05:00'
      maxTime:'10:00'**